# Would anyone ever actually call it “Neo-Tokyo”?

Tags: internal-consistency, culture

In the official documents, I mean. The name “Neo-Tokyo”, made famous by the landmark animated film Akira, is well-known enough that using it in reference to cyberpunk, anime, cyberpunk anime, and anything inspired by the above will inevitably garner just as many groans as it does nods and chuckles (see Jaden Smith’s latest abomination). But is it really such a dead horse that nobody would even think of using the name in a serious context anymore?

Let’s allow ourselves to dream for a second. Imagine that, in the near future, Tokyo is either totally devastated by some large-scale natural disaster like another earthquake/mega-tsunami like in 2011, or it’s completely destroyed in a nuclear exchange with North Korea (whichever one you prefer will probably say a lot about how you see the world). Either way, the greater Tokyo area is completely beyond saving. After centuries of enduring, it’s just been trashed to the point where no one could possibly hope to repair it.

Because this is 20 minutes in the future, someone inevitably proposes building an artificial island in the bay a safe distance from the disaster/radioactive exclusion zone, and eventually someone, doesn’t matter who or how many, suggests they name the new island “Neo-Tokyo” specifically in reference to Akira. Would anyone actually support this given the cultural significance of Akira (and the fact that this is Japan lol), or would it be seen as tasteless/disrespectful/kinda corny? What do you all think?

(as you may or may not be able to tell, I decided to ask this question basically because I was bored and thought it was funny :P)

Comment: Even old New York was once New Amsterdam... So why not Neo Tokyo? I suspect that in Japanese it woud be the Classical Chinese equivalent of the Greek "neo-", but it's not unusual for such prefixes to get translated. After all, the French name *Nouvelle Orléans* became *New Orleans* in English...

Comment: Probably 新東京 (shintoukyou) but I have no idea of this is consistent with the Akira film since it's been a while since I saw it.

Comment: Is a sufficient portion of the general population (not just your particular subculture) familiar enough with that film and the cyberpunk, anime, cyberpunk anime &c genres that "Neo Tokyo" would really be a dead horse?  I wouldn't be surprised to find that most involved in making the government & financial decisions needed to build such a place are not.

Comment: I think the one reason to question the possibility would be that Neo is an unusual prefix.  "New" is more typical.  The Japanese would probably need a reason to borrow a word AND pick a really strange one.

Comment: @AlexP, spoken like someone who doesn't know where York is ;)

Comment: New [York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/York), New [Brunswick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunswick), New [Zealand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeeland)... of course people want to call things New Whatever.

Comment: I started to write a long answer... I'll make it short here. Most likely, it will not happen since it is not normal for Japanese to use 新 (new) in the names of cities and towns. I think that either they will come up with a completely new name (as it's been done historically) or they will continue the recent tradition of retaining 京 (capital; 京都→東京) In this case, 新京 (Shinkyō; new capital) or cardinal direction (東 means East) ＋京 would be more plausible. BTW, 京 means the sit of the Emperor. So if the Imperial family dies, 京 might be abandoned. 東京 (Tōkyō) means the east sit of the Emperor.

Answer (score 4):

Calling the new city *New Whatever* mentally sets it apart it from *Old Whatever*. Why would you want that, and why not?

- The old city is for all practical purposes **gone**, but the memory lingers. Everybody knows that *Whatever* is a wasteland of slums and pestilence. So you decide to build *New Whatever*, a shining city on the hill. Completely different from the ruins nearby.
- The old city is **still there** and you need the distinction. So you have new quarters and old quarters. Think [New Territories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Territories) or [Neue Länder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_states_of_Germany). After a couple or centuries, the "new" might stay in common usage while the reason is forgotten.
- For some legal reasons you want the distinction, so you use the new name in official usage. "Oh no, *New Whatever* is definitely not paying the debts of *Old Whatever*. Go sue the landfill, not us."